# PHPUnit feature tests pass locally but not in Github Actions

Tags: laravel, phpunit, github-actions, laravel-9

I have a set of tests that pass locally, but once I push to Github, the tests fail. The Github Action seems like a black box to me, and I'm unsure of even how to troubleshoot this. I'm using in-memory sqlite both locally and in my github action workflow.

I'm inserting some data for my tests, and at the beginning of these seeder classes, I'm temporarily disabling foreign keys to allow me to truncate the tables:

```
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
QuickbooksTransaction::truncate();
Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

Here's the start of my test class that's producing the errors:

```
class FindMatchesTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase, WithFaker;

    protected $user;
    protected $client;
    protected $location;
    protected $statement;

    public function setup(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->setupFaker();
        $this->seed();
        $this->user = User::factory()->create();
        $this->client = Client::factory()->create();
        $this->location = Location::factory()->create();
        $this->statement = Statement::factory()->create();
        $this->seed(StatementTransactionSeeder::class); //truncates and populates a table
        $this->seed(TransactionSeeder::class); //truncates and populates a table

        $action = new FindMatches($this->statement, true);
        $action->handle();
    }
```

this is the first of 3 tests that are failing. It doesn't matter which assertion I put first, they all fail:

```
  public function test_right_matching_invoice_nbr_produces_match()
    {
        $row = StatementTransaction::where('invoice_nbr', '999999654321')->first();
        $qbRow = Transaction::where('invoice_nbr', '888888654321')->first();

        $this->assertNotEmpty($row->transaction_id);
        $this->assertEquals(1, $row->has_partial_match);
        $this->assertEquals(0, $row->has_match);
        $this->assertEquals(0, $row->has_identified_match);
        $this->assertEquals($row->transaction_id, $qbRow->id);
        $this->assertGreaterThanOrEqual(Config::get('match_threshold'), $row->invoice_nbr_match_confidence);
    }
```

If I leave the order that's above, I get `Failed asserting that 7 matches expected 8.`

If I switch the order up and put the next row first, I get `Failed asserting that 1 matches expected 0.`

It's almost like it's seeeing different data than what I'm seeing locally, but that doesn't seem possible if it's running it the same way as it is locally.

Could there be a difference in how PHPUnit would run locally and how it would run in Github actions? Is there a way to see the data it's seeing when it runs so I can begin to troubleshoot this?

Here is my Github Action config file:

```
name: LaravelTest

on:
  push:
    branches: [ test ]

jobs:
  laravel_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@main
      - name: Copy .env
        run: php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress
      - name: Generate key
        run: php artisan key:generate
      - name: Directory Permissions
        run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
      - name: Create Database
        run: |
          mkdir -p database
          touch database/database.sqlite
      - name: Compile assets
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run production
      - name: Execute tests (Unit and Feature tests) via PHPUnit
        env:
          DB_CONNECTION: sqlite
          DB_DATABASE: database/database.sqlite
          CACHE_DRIVER: array
          SESSION_DRIVER: array
          QUEUE_DRIVER: sync
        run: vendor/bin/phpunit
  forge_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: laravel_tests
    steps:
      - name: Make Get Request
        uses: satak/webrequest-action@master
        with:
          url: ${{ secrets.TEST_DEPLOY_URL }}
          method: GET
```

EDIT: adding the seeder classes. Both classes are close to identical, with just a bunch of insert statements to create the dummy records for testing.

```
class TransactionSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Transaction::truncate();
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();

       $id = Statement::first()->id;
       $inv = Helper::cleanInvoiceNumber('888888654321');
       $date = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d');

        DB::table('transactions')->insert([
            'statement_id' => $id,
            'transaction_type_id' => 1,
            'transaction_date' => $date,
            'invoice_nbr' => '888888654321',
            'invoice_nbr_clean' => $inv,
            'original_amount' => '16100',
            'balance' => '16100',
            'row_hash' =>  Helper::makeHash([
                $id,
                1,
                $inv,
                $date,
                '16100'
            ])
        ]);

//...more inserts like above...
}
```

```
class StatementTransactionSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        StatementTransaction::truncate();
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();

        $id = Statement::first()->id;
        $inv = Helper::cleanInvoiceNumber('999999654321');
        $date = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d');

        DB::table('statement_transactions')->insert([
            'statement_id' => $id,
            'transaction_type_id' => 1,
            'transaction_date' => $date,
            'invoice_nbr' => '999999654321',
            'invoice_nbr_clean' => $inv,
            'po_nbr' => 'Right 6 match',
            'original_amount' => '16100',
            'balance' => '16100',
            'row_hash' =>  Helper::makeHash([
                $id,
                1,
                $inv,
                $date,
                '16100'
            ])
        ]);

//...more inserts like above...
}
```

**Clarification requested in comment:**

When I say switch the order, I just mean that the first assertion always fails in this test, regardless of the order of the assert statements. So this:

```
 $this->assertNotEmpty($row->transaction_id);
 $this->assertEquals(1, $row->has_partial_match);
```

or this:

```
 $this->assertEquals(1, $row->has_partial_match);
 $this->assertNotEmpty($row->transaction_id);
```

will both fail on the first assert statement it hits. This, combined with the error message it spits out, leads me to believe that the data isn't the same on the server as it is locally for some reason.

**UPDATE**

Based on feedback in the comments, I updated the line to get the statement with this: `$id = Statement::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->id;`

Now all the tests in this class are failing with the message:  `You requested 1 items, but there are only 0 items available.`.

I have no idea what this means. Currently wading through google results.

**UPDATE 2**

Ok that was wrong. I think I incorrectly removed a line of code for a factory that wasn't needed in the test, but was a dependency for another factory.

I'm back at square one.

**UPDATE 3**

In an effort to not spend my entire life on this, I'm going back to the drawing board and eliminating the seeder classes and just inserting the records I need for the specific test inside the test itself. Hoping this resolves the issue so I don't have to jump off a cliff in despair.

Comment: Would help if you shared the seeding code since, as your first guess, the irregularity seems to be in the seeding. also can you be more precise in "If I switch the order up and put the next row first" ?

Comment: What is `$id` in `'statement_id' => $id,`?

Comment: Sorry, left out a line: `$id = Statement::first()->id;` Everything else is there.

Comment: `first()` can be arbitrary depending on installation. Add some orderBy() or switch to static ID values since you know it is from scratch. (the auto incrementing might not be reset after truncated or not reset to 1)

Comment: ok, that at least gives me tests that are failing consistently locally and in github. Now all my tests for this class fail with this message: "You requested 1 items, but there are only 0 items available." I feel like that's progress. Now I need to figure out what this error message means and where it's encountering the error.